# Trying to write datatable to Excel using ClosedXML in C# WinForms app

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I'm trying to create an Excel file writing a datatable in C#. I'm using ClosedXML. Here is the code I'm using:

dtbl is a datatable, fileNameFullPath is a string to a valid directory.

```
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dtbl);

        wb.SaveAs(fileNameFullPath);
    }
```

It's throwing the following error:

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.IdPartPair> DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.get_Parts()'.
  Source=ClosedXML
  StackTrace:
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreateParts(SpreadsheetDocument document, SaveOptions options)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.CreatePackage(String filePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType spreadsheetDocumentType, SaveOptions options)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(String file, SaveOptions options)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(String file, Boolean validate, Boolean evaluateFormulae)
   at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook.SaveAs(String file)
   at MatchingPolicyToAC.MatchingProcess.SaveToExcel(DataGridView dtgv, DataGridEnum dgenm, String sname) in C:\_Source_DevOps\PolicyMatching\MatchingPolicyToAC\MatchingPolicyToAC\MatchingProcess\MatchingProcess.cs:line 418

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    MatchingPolicyToAC.MatchingProcess.SaveToExcel(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView, MatchingPolicyToAC.DataGridEnum, string) in MatchingProcess.cs
```

I'm using v0.101.0 ClosedXML, and v3.0.0-ci0083 of DocumentFormat.OpenXml

I'm writing in C#, Visual Studio 2022 v4.6.1 Windows App.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

ClosedXML is developed based on OpenXML. You must use the OpenXML version recommended by closedXML. If you upgrade the OpenXML version alone, this phenomenon may occur.